# Is there a way to force a browser's Window object to re-assess where the mouse is?

Tags: javascript, iframe, mouse

I have a content management tool that uses iframes to stack blocks of content on a page. The system will load the contents of each block into the iframe, along with a cover and some buttons for editing functions (edit, delete, copy and move). The cover only appears on mouseover (using the CSS :hover pseudo-class), so the content of the page looks exactly like it would live, except when the user mouses over the block they want to edit. This all works fine.

The problem comes with moving the block. I have developed a drag-and-drop system for moving the blocks. The user will mouse-down on the move icon, then drag the block to where they need it. On mousedown, the block itself (the whole iframe) is hidden (display:none), and is replaced with a shadow div of the same shape, which is then dragged around. If the user chooses to drop the block in a new place, everything works fine, but if they drop it anywhere else, the operation is cancelled. The shadow is destryoed, and the original iframe is re-displayed.

Now the problem: when the original iframe is re-displayed, it still thinks that the mouse is hovering over it, and all the layers that only display under the :hover pseudo-class are showing (In FireFox and IE - not in Chrome). Moving the mouse over the block then out again resets the iframe state, but I'm looking for a way to force the iframe to re-assess the mouse position without the user having to do anything.

One solution is to replace the use of the pseudo classes with mouse events and specified classes, but I'm wondering if there are any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're targeting only the newest browsers (in older IE's there was no native :hover event for anything other than anchor) you should skip the :hover approach and go with what you're (correctly) assuming is a solution - meaning use of css classes and js events to determine state of a block.